# Formatting golang time for Azure SDK

Tags: azure, go, time, azure-blob-storage

Consider the following golang

```
today :=  time.Now().Format("2006-01-02T03:04:05.9999999Z")
t, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339Nano, today)
```

Why isn't that equivalent to the much simpler

```
t := time.Now()
```

?

I would like to confirm whether the above code is equivalent, as I believe it is, or why it isn't, based on my current experience. I also provide additional context regarding what I've attempted.

My full repo code [here in GitHub](https://github.com/giuliohome-org/go-azure) in the `main.go` file. However, for the purpose of this question, let's focus on the code snippet provided below.

```
sasToken, err := client.ListAccountSAS(
    ctx, resourceGroupName, storageAccountName, armstorage.AccountSasParameters{
    KeyToSign:              to.Ptr("key1"),
    SharedAccessExpiryTime: to.Ptr(func() time.Time { 
        t, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339Nano, tomorrow); return t }()),
    Permissions:            to.Ptr(armstorage.PermissionsR),
    Protocols:              to.Ptr(armstorage.HTTPProtocolHTTPSHTTP),
    ResourceTypes:          to.Ptr(armstorage.SignedResourceTypesS),
    Services:               to.Ptr(armstorage.ServicesB),
    SharedAccessStartTime:  to.Ptr(func() time.Time { 
        t, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339Nano, today); return t }()),
}, nil)
```

Currently, this code is functioning as expected. However, [when I simplify the last line](https://github.com/giuliohome-org/go-azure/commit/bbdf1f0249516c372b27016ab654e733b9045656) to `t := time.Now()`, it results in an error (shown in [Run job](https://github.com/giuliohome-org/go-azure/actions/runs/6219693310/job/16878246928) of Github Actions).

```
today 2023-09-18T07:54:42.6314723Z should be formatted as 2023-09-16T11:42:03.1567373Z
tomorrow 2023-09-19T07:54:42.6314723Z should be formattes as 2023-09-17T11:42:03.1567373Z
2023/09/18 07:54:43 POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/go-azure-sdk/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/golangazure/ListAccountSas
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RESPONSE 400: 400 Bad Request
ERROR CODE: InvalidValuesForRequestParameters
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidValuesForRequestParameters",
    "message": "Values for request parameters are invalid: signedStart."
  }
}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
exit status 1
```

This has led me to question why the equivalence doesn't hold, contrary to my initial expectation.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @derpirscher Thank you! Give me a few minutes, I do the change in the github code so that we can see the error in github action log (and I'll update the question as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That API expect the time rounded to second. So try something like:

```
...
            SharedAccessExpiryTime: to.Ptr(expiryTime.Round(time.Second)),
...
            SharedAccessStartTime:  to.Ptr(startTime.Round(time.Second)),
...
```

Comment: Yes, tested, I confirm it works, thanks but  - before accepting it -please I still fail to see why my original code was working without rounding to the second and why that equivalence doesn't hold.

Comment: which API Version are you using? maybe could be an issue with older api. Consider the latest 2023-01-01 refer to code example like you pasted https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storage-accounts/list-account-sas?tabs=HTTP#storageaccountlistaccountsas

Comment: my go.mod is here https://github.com/giuliohome-org/go-azure/blob/main/go.mod

Comment: if you check from the UI, the max precision you can set is to `second`

Comment: sure, I already fixed the code as per your suggestion, I just want to understand what is going on from the point of view of golang before I close this topic. (btw the final UTC() is not relevant)

Answer (score 1):

I now understand that - from the point of view of golang code - the root issue boils down to the concept of  [monotonic clock reading](https://pkg.go.dev/time#hdr-Monotonic_Clocks):

> The Time returned by time.Now contains a monotonic clock reading.

This inclusion of the monotonic clock reading is what can cause issues in certain scenarios, possibly due to some internal interpretation of the parameter. However, there is no such monotonic clock reading when using the `time.Parse` function.

It's worth noting that because the monotonic clock reading has no meaning outside the current process, various functions and methods in Go's `time` package handle it differently. Functions like `t.Round(d)` strip the monotonic clock reading from their results. This behavior is why the accepted answer works, as it leverages such functions to achieve the desired outcome.

**Edit**

I've also located where the problem likely resides in the [SDK source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/blob/main/sdk/storage/azblob/sas/query_params.go#L31). The issue lies in the time formats used by the SDK, which are as follows:

```
var timeFormats = []string{
    "2006-01-02T15:04:05.0000000Z",
    TimeFormat,
    "2006-01-02T15:04Z",
    "2006-01-02",
}
```

The crucial detail here is that the first time format contains only 7 decimal places. This explains why I had to use `Format("2006-01-02T03:04:05.9999999Z")` instead of the simpler `Format(time.RFC3339Nano)`.

Their [documentation about the access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas#specify-the-access-policy) specifies the [Accepted ISO 8601 UTC formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/formatting-datetime-values#accepted-iso-8601-utc-formats).
It mentions:

> If the time value includes seconds, it may optionally also include up to 7 decimal digits of fractional seconds, following the pattern hh:mm:ss[.f{1,7}]. This pattern is supported by the Azure Storage APIs, tools, and client libraries.

Hence `Round(time.Microsecond)` would still work but attempting to round with `Round(time.Nanosecond)` would fail.

Comment: @Matteo thank you again for your help and your solution. Actually that is what makes sense to do.